# Count objects after using activerecord joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I just noticed that using `.size` or `.count` on a query that has `joins` gives unexpected results.

```
User.some_scope.size #=> 10
User.joins(:associations).some_scope.size #=> 10 + associated object count
```

How do I get the count of Users that fit the scope no matter what I join onto the table?

Some of the actual code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tracking_logs, class_name: "Tracking::Log", dependent: :destroy
end

class Tracking::Log < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

User.where(created_at: Time.now-1.day..Time.now).size #=> 18
SQL: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"  WHERE ("users"."created_at" BETWEEN '2015-05-25 10:40:11.423142' AND '2015-05-26 10:40:11.423741')
User.joins(:tracking_logs).where(created_at: Time.now-1.day..Time.now).size #=> 3188
SQL: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "tracking_logs" ON "tracking_logs"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE ("users"."created_at" BETWEEN '2015-05-25 10:41:15.260113' AND '2015-05-26 10:41:15.260684')
```

I expect `.size` to be applied only to the base model I call the query on, anything else is just confusing.

**NB**, being explicit about which model's created_at to check does not change the result e.g.

```
User.joins(:tracking_logs).where( users: { created_at: Time.now-1.day..Time.now } ).size #=> 3188
SQL: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "tracking_logs" ON "tracking_logs"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE ("users"."created_at" BETWEEN '2015-05-25 10:49:29.485508' AND '2015-05-26 10:49:29.486120')

User attributes:
               :id => :integer,
         :category => :string,
            :email => :string,
       :created_at => :datetime,
       :updated_at => :datetime,
           :locale => :string,
   :original_email => :text,
  :registration_id => :integer,
       :first_name => :text,
      :login_count => :integer,
       :offer_type => :text,
              :cid => :string,
   :fb_like_status => :integer,
:product_purchases => :text

Tracking::Log attributes:
                  :id => :integer,
             :user_id => :integer,
 :tracking_referer_id => :integer,
                  :to => :string,
     :controller_name => :string,
         :action_name => :string,
:tracking_activity_id => :integer,
 :time_since_last_log => :integer,
          :created_at => :datetime,
          :updated_at => :datetime
```

Comment: Can you provide some of your code. Like the models and data on which it happens? I cannot seem to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Same here. Could you try turning on logging with `ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)` and showing SQL that gets generated for the first and the second query?

Comment: which created at you want to compare users or tracking_logs?

Comment: Users'. Looking at the query I am wondering how activerecord resolves the collision of attribute names. Would being explicit solve this?

Comment: And what are the fields of each table? And what does pure SQL query yield you `SELECT * FROM "users" INNER JOIN "tracking_logs" ON "tracking_logs"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE ("users"."created_at" BETWEEN '2015-05-25 10:41:15.260113' AND '2015-05-26 10:41:15.260684')` (curious of the field names in particular)?

Comment: Not sure about raw SQL usage. Tried `sql = %Q|SELCT ... |` and `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)`. The result is not a number, but `#<PG::Result:0x007f82c027a228 status=PGRES_TUPLES_OK ntuples=3183 nfields=24 cmd_tuples=3183>`

Comment: I think the problem is that it will return each user joined with a specific tracking log. If you add uniq like this it should probalby return what you want: `User.joins(:tracking_logs).where(created_at: Time.now-1.day..Time.now).uniq.size` but there is probably some better way to get to this result.

Comment: do you get the same result with `count`? which rails version do you use?

Comment: @EgonWilzer `.uniq` does trim the unneeded tracking logs, but there is an edge case where it does not work - if there are users with no logs.

Comment: @apneadiving `count` returns the same value. Project runs Rails 4.1.4, Ruby 2.1.2

Comment: You will get no users that don't have any logs. When you use joins it will do an inner join and return only users with logs.

Comment: Guess that will have to do. Feel free to make it a proper answer with references to a doc or two so I can accept. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the joins will return the same user multiple times, if the user has more than one tracking log. You can use uniq to get each user only once:

```
User.joins(:tracking_logs).where(created_at: Time.now-1.day..Time.now).uniq.size
```

See also here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-a-single-association